# splitting a single row command to two parts so it would be more "structured" aesthetically

Tags: shell

I have the following command which I run from a script. In the script file it is written in this somewhat long row:

```
sudo zip -r /var/www/html/html-$(date +\%F-\%T-).zip /var/www/html -x /var/www/html/wp-content/cache
```

---

So far so good, but I want to split this command into a few pieces **horizontally**, like:

```
sudo zip -r /var/www/html/html-$(date +\%F-\%T-).zip /var/www/html || -x /var/www/html/wp-content/cache
```

<sub>Where `||` should come non-executed characters that will use just for "aeshtetic" splitting of the command to two parts.</sub>

Or maybe even vertically like:

```
sudo zip -r /var/www/html/html-$(date +\%F-\%T-).zip /var/www/html 
-x /var/www/html/wp-content/cache
```

---

What will you say is the best way to achieve that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If I correctly understand what you're trying to achieve, you should use `\`. This allows splitting long commands into multiple lines.

```
sudo zip -r \
    /var/www/html/html-$(date +\%F-\%T-).zip \
    /var/www/html \
    -x /var/www/html/wp-content/cache
```

Keep in mind that spaces before slashes are important. Shells don't insert them automatically, so command like

```
echo\
"asdf"
```

will likely result in a "command not found" (@ilkkachu).

Comment: And **no** whitespace behind the slash!

Comment: in other words: the backslash is here used to escape the Newline that comes right after it, so that the shell doesn't interpret it as an end of command but instead just a literral newline. So the backslash is **immediately before the newline**.

Comment: Hmm why should that `echo\<nl>    asdf` give an error? (or is that just a presentation typo?) The backslash eats the newline, and the spaces in front of the next line separate the words, resulting in the two words `echo` and `asdf`. `echo\<nl>asdf` would be different, that's the same as `echoasdf`, which probably gives "command not found"

Comment: @ilkkachu yeah, that's what I actually meant. thanks.

Comment: @OlivierDulac: No, the backslash doesn't make the shell interpret the newline as a literal newline, it makes the shell interpret the newline as "nothing at all". Which is why echo\<nl>"asdf" doesn't echo asdf - it concatenates to echo"asdf" -> echoasdf which results in that command not found error.

Comment: @GuntramBlohm: you're right.